# "No such file or directory" error when using Ansible's "net_put" and libssh to a cisco switch

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible but have followed various examples online for transferring an image file to a Cisco ios device (Catalyst 2960x). I've chosen to use `ansible.netcommon.net_put` to transfer the file via SCP from the Ansible host to the device. However, I continually receive the following error:

> fatal: [test_bench]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "destination":
> "flash:/test.bin", "msg": "Exception received: Error transferring file
> to flash:/test.bin: Initializing SCP session of remote file
> [flash:/test.bin] for write failed with error [b'Socket error: No such
> file or directory']"}

I've also seen two more errors, with no apparent rhyme or reason, other than timing: `[b'Socket error: Broken pipe']` and `[b'Socket error: Inappropriate ioctl for device']`

It is reproducible with this single playbook:

```
---
# Ansible Playbook to upgrade switch firmware.

# Cisco IOS handler
- name: UPGRADE SWITCHES
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: COPY IMAGE TO DEVICE
      ansible.netcommon.net_put:
        src: "files/{{ firmware }}"
        dest: "flash:/{{ firmware }}"
      vars:
        ansible_command_timeout: 1200
        # ansible_network_cli_ssh_type: paramiko # Bypass libssh bug by using paramiko
```

The device is configured with the following options in inventory:

```
"_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
        "test_bench": {
            "MD5": "1b3781db619dcce6a2677628acc15439",
            "ansible_become": true,
            "ansible_become_method": "enable",
            "ansible_connection": "ansible.netcommon.network_cli",
            "ansible_host": "172.22.143.50",
            "ansible_network_os": "cisco.ios.ios",
            "ansible_password": {
                "__ansible_vault": "$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.2;AES256;admin\n<removed for privacy>"
            },
            "ansible_user": "admin",
            "firmware": "c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E8.bin",
            "target_version": "15.2(7)E8"
        }
    }
}
```

This is running in a test environment on my workstation in WSL2. All other tasks using `libssh` connecting to this device consistently works fine. It's only this `net_put` scp connection that fails all the time.

The errors all seem to suggest some type of issue with the local socket connection. I've tried the following:

1. Transferring the file manually via SCP - no problems.
2. Running `ansible-playbook` as root.
3. Running in a clean Ubuntu devcontainer on top of WSL.
4. Setting `ansible_become` to `false`
5. Deleting any persistent connections in `~/.ansible/pc`
6. Running `strace` on `ansible-playbook` - I'm no expert here but I see one process ID create the socket, and a couple other process IDs try to access it at `/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0` (for example). I do see the result being `No such file or directory` at times even though it is successfully created. Almost seems like a race condition. See below.
7. I looked through the source code, the failure occurs when pylibssh calls the `libssh.ssh_scp_init` method. But, I didn't go any further. (See line 64 here: https://github.com/ansible/pylibssh/blob/devel/src/pylibsshext/scp.pyx)
8. Switching from `libssh` to `paramiko` as seen in the code sample. **THIS WORKS!!!**

Filtered strace output:

```
vscode ➜ ~ $ grep -i 3a091fe6a0 strace2.log

98522 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", 0x7ffc1921afb0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
98522 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", 0x7ffc1921afb0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
98524 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", 0x7ffdbcaf2920, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
98524 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/.ansible_pc_lock_3a091fe6a0",  <unfinished ...>
98524 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/.ansible_pc_lock_3a091fe6a0", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_CLOEXEC, 0600) = 3
98524 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", 0x7ffdbcaf2920, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
98528 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", 0x7ffdbcaf1f70, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
98528 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", 0x7ffdbcaf1f70, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
98528 bind(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, 38 <unfinished ...>
98524 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
98524 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
98524 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, 38 <unfinished ...>
98528 <... getsockname resumed>{sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, [128 => 38]) = 0
98522 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
98522 connect(12, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, 38 <unfinished ...>
98528 <... getsockname resumed>{sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, [128 => 38]) = 0
98522 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0",  <unfinished ...>
98522 connect(12, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, 38 <unfinished ...>
98528 <... getsockname resumed>{sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, [128 => 38]) = 0
98522 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0", {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
98522 connect(12, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, 38 <unfinished ...>
98528 <... getsockname resumed>{sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/home/vscode/.ansible/pc/3a091fe6a0"}, [128 => 38]) = 0
```

Why is this not working with `libssh` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can redo the playbook to login and pull the file via SCP. (I'm having the same issue with ansible core 2.13.11.  This is particularly annoying as paramiko is still broken.)

Comment: Please don't add "me too" answers. If you have a **NEW** question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, you can press the follow button and be notified of any new answers. Additionally, if you [have enough reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), you can set a [bounty](//stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to help attract more attention to the question.